emacs-like key-bindings for window management within macOS
Is there a way to have macOS key-bindings that let me manipulate windows?
For example:

⌘ Command → to move the window to the right
⌘ Command + →
to grow the window to the right

I'm looking for tools to help me minimize my trackpad usage.

There are quite a few „window management“ questions on this site already, some of the answers might fit in your case as well. What have you already done in terms of research, what have you found?

I've looked a bit into yabai and found it buggy for the case i mentioned. I'm an emacs user, so looking for something very much like it to manage my windows instead.

There is Raycast which have Window Management extension with possibility to set hotkeys.

I have been using Spectacle for quite sometime now. You can move a window to the left or right with:
⌘ Command ⌥ Option →
OR
⌘ Command ⌥ Option ←
Best of all it is completely free to use.
